# how to validate login before action?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, koa

I am using `koa` and `Typescript` to implement many apis, but in some apis, I need to check if user is login, I do like this:

```
export async function list_products(req: product.list_normal.Request):promise<product.list_normal.Response> {
    // no need to check login here
    ....
    return products;
}

export async function pay(req: shop.pay.Request): promise<shop.pay.Response> {
    const isLogin = this.session && this.session.userInfo && this.session.userInfo.userId;
    // check login here
    if (!isLogin) {
        return {
            errorId: "need_login.error",
            errorDesc: "please login"
        }
    }

    ...

    return resp
}
```

the problem is that I **need to do this each time**, I want to something like this:

```
function need_login(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        const req = args[0]
        if (!req.factoryUserId) {
            return {
                errorId: "need_login_error",
                errorDesc: "please login",
            }
        } else {
            let result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);               // run and store the result
            return result;                                               // return the result of the original method
        }
    };

    return descriptor;
}

export async function list_products(req) {
    ....

    return products;
}

@need_login
export async function pay(req) {
    ...

    return resp
}
```

as you can see, I add a decorator `need_login` in `pay` method, this should be great, however `Typescript` decorator can not use in function:

```
Decorators are not valid here
```

So I am asking **do I have any choice to do this easy**?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with middlewares. For example, if you use [koa-router](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router), you can set up 2 differents routers, one for public routes and the other one for authenticated routes. For example:

```
koa = require('koa');
KoaRouter = require('koa-router');

app = koa();

publicRouter = new KoaRouter();
publicRouter.get('/products', httpTier.getProducts);
app.use(publicRouter.routes());

privateRouter = new KoaRouter({prefix: '/private'});
privateRouter.use(need_login);
privateRouter.post('/checkout', httpTier.pay);
app.use(privateRouter.routes());
```

Thus, all routes starting with "/private" will require an authentication using the need_login middleware.